# Sequelize validation - is it possible to have Sequelize group errors by attribute/field?

Tags: validation, error-handling, sequelize.js

I am new to Sequelize having previously mainly used Yii2 ActiveRecord as an ORM.

Regarding Sequelize validation, currently I am only getting errors back in the following format: -

```
"errors": [
    {
        "message": "notNull Violation: modelname.model_attribute cannot be null,",
    }
]
```

Does Sequelize have any intrinsic method to return errors in the following format?

```
"errors": [
    {
        "modelname": 
            {
                "model_attribute": ["cannot be null"]
            }
    }
]
```

I would find that a bit more sane for working with form errors etc via API calls.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

About the same format, I'm not sure, but for custom message add validation function in your model like this:

```
battery_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(66),
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          len: {
            args: [0, 60],
            msg: 'Some custom message'
          },
          notEmpty: {
            msg: 'Another custom message'
          }
        }
      }
```

More info here: https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/docs/models-definition/#validations

Also, you can add catch like this to group error as you with:

```
SequelizeModel.create({}).then(() => { /* ... */ }).catch(Sequelize.ValidationError, e => {
   /* create logic to group/format/change default sequelize error */ 
})
```